# Additional imports in setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

My project

```
myproject/
   setup.py
   myproject/
      __init__.py
      helper_cy.pyx
      main.py
```

won't install using `pip` when the `setup.py` additionally imports `cythonize` from `Cython.Build`.

```
#setup.py

from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import setup

setup(
   name='mypackage',
   version='0.0.10',
   author='John Doe',
   author_email='john_doe@yahoo.com',
   packages=['mypackage'],
   ext_modules=cythonize('myproject/helper_cy.pyx')
   zip_safe=False
)
```

`pip` replies along the lines of

```
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [20 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):

[...]

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
[end of output]
```

I'm experiencing the same thing if I try to import `numpy` in the `setup.py` instead of `Cython` and exclude the `ext_module` from `setup()`. Which makes me believe that it has to do with importing additional packages in `setup.py`.

My `Python` version is `3.11.5` and `Cython` is version `3.0.2`.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't show things "along the lines of": show the real, full error. Although of course the error is pretty much the authority here: you're importing from a library that is not installed for the context you're running in. I don't see [an `install_requires` list in your setup](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies), so start there. Add your package dependency as per the docs instead of trying to import in setup.py itself.